# Error while loading electron-tabs module & unable to create tabs in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I have installed electron-modules package for implementing tabs in electron as shown below

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Backoffice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "BackOffice application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "Karthik",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.8",
    "electron-tabs": "^0.9.4"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const Menu = electron.Menu;
const path = require("path");
const url = require("url");
const TabGroup = require("electron-tabs");

let win;
const tabGroup = new TabGroup();

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow();
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname:path.join(__dirname,'index.html'),
        protocol:'file',
        slashes:true
    }));

    win.on('closed',()=>{
        win = null;
    })
}

app.on('ready', function(){
    createWindow();
    const template = [
        {
            label : 'Backoffice',
            submenu: [
                {
                   label : 'Account Management',
                   click : function () {
                       let tab = tabGroup.addTab({
                       title: "Electron",
                       src: "http://electron.atom.io",
                       visible: true
                    });
                    }
                },
                {
                    label : 'HR Management',
                    click : function () {
                        console.log("CLICK HM menu");
                    }    
                },
             ]

        }
]
    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>BackOffice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/electron-tabs/electron-tabs.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>BackOffice</h1>
        <div class="etabs-tabgroup">
            <div class="etabs-tabs"></div>
            <div class="etabs-buttons"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="etabs-views"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error when I run npm start

```
App threw an error during loadReferenceError: document is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\nodejs_workspace\electron\menu-demo\node_modules\electron-tabs\index.js:3:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\nodejs_workspace\electron\menu-demo\node_modules\electron-tabs\index.js:421:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\DEV_2018\nodejs_workspace\electron\menu-demo\main.js:11:18)
```

- Why am I not able to load electron-modules package.
- What is causing this error? How to create a new tab on click on
  application menu in electron?

Comment: Please suggest the module to be imported in electron to implement tabs on click of menu if the 'electron-tabs' is not the correct module for implementing tabs in electron.

Comment: Basically my requirement is to implement tabs we see in eclipse IDE. A new tab opens on click on each source file and we can also drag the tab in eclipse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @coolreader18 explained in details, you have to use `electron-tabs` in *Renderer process*

This means you have to notify the html from main.js when you click a menu item. [`MenuItem`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item#new-menuitemoptions)'s click provides you the caller `BrowserWindow` so you can send message to it.

*main.js*

```js
 ...
 {
   label: 'Account Management',
   click: function (menuItem, browserWindow, event) {
     browserWindow.webContents.send('add-tab', {
       title: 'Electron',
       src: 'http://electron.atom.io',
       visible: true
     })
   }
 },
 ...
```

*index.html*

```js
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
    const TabGroup = require('electron-tabs')
    const tabGroup = new TabGroup()

    ipcRenderer.on('add-tab', (event, arg) => {
      tabGroup.addTab(arg)
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-tabs#usage) for `electron-tabs`, it mentions to call it from the renderer process, yet you're doing it in the main process. The main process is where you control the electron apis from, e.g. opening windows like you are in `main.js`. Each browser window creates a new renderer process, which can communicate with the main process or manage its own document and Web APIS.

The error you're getting there, `document is not defined`, is because the main process does not have access to the DOM because you can open multiple browsers from the same main process; it wouldn't know which to use. So what you need to do is put a script in the renderer process. Create a `renderer.js`, and put the `electron-tabs` code (`const TabGroup = require("electron-tabs");`) there. Then, in your `index.html`, put `<script src="renderer.js"></script>`, and it should work.

Comment: I get an error - Reference Error : tabGroup is not defined in main.js when I moved the electron-tabs code(const TabGroup = require("electron-tabs"); to render.js. I believe TabGroup code should be there in main.js itself as I want open a tab on click of any menu and the menu code is in main.js

Comment: It would be helpful & more clear to me if you can paste the whole source code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I believe TabGroup code should be there in main.js" No, it should not. You have to initialize it in Renderer and just _notify_ from Main

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The menu stuff that you manage in `main.js` is the top menu bar, like File, Edit, View, etc. ALL the `electron-tabs` code should be in `renderer.js`, so anything that references TabGroup. That's why you're getting that error, because `const tabGroup = new TabGroup()` and `tabGroup.addTab(...)` is still in `main.js`. To communicate from the main process to the renderer process, which it seems like you want to do upon a menu bar event, look at [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) and [ipcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer).

Comment: using ipc from MenuItems properly may be tricky, see my answer with working code

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you are calling

```
const tabGroup = new TabGroup();
```

before the page has finished loading.

Try splitting it up into

```
let tabGroup;
```

and inside of createWindow():

```
tabGroup = new TabGroup();
```

**Edit:** You have to change const to let or var then, sorry

Comment: I still get same error. The error is at line const TabGroup = require("electron-tabs").

Comment: Did you install the module correctly? If you get an error during the require() function, it could be related to your package installation. Try to make a clean install: https://github.com/brrd/electron-tabs

Comment: I have installed the module correctly. I have installed version 0.9.4. const TabGroup = require("electron-tabs") works fine if it is used inside index.html. I guess this issue is because tabGroup is not able to find HTML document object.